# see events defined on a MooTools element in console

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there an easy way to see, in the console, what events are defined for a MooTools element?

For example, if I have a link with id 'link_with_event' on which I've added a click event, is there something like `$('link_with_event').events` that I could type into the console and see that click even I've defined?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible through [retrieve method](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3aretrieve). On each mootools Element, events are [stored](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3astore) with 'events' key. To display all the events associated with a specific element, just retrieve them :

```
var myElement = $('myElement'); //grab elem

myElement.addEvent('click',function(){alert('clicked')}); //add event

console.log(myElement.retrieve('events')); //log added events
```

demo => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/5xxcP/

Answer (score 0):

In Firebug, use the "HTML" tab:
On the right side are a series of sub tabs, including one called "Events".
This shows the events that have been registered for each element, and any events that have been inherited.
In the DOM tab you can see all extensions of the element.

All browsers have similar capabilities in their developer tools.